# Unexpected 403 error on my webpage

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've got an unexpected 403 error on a webpage of my website. I made no recent changed to my site at all and I've got no idea where the error is coming from. The page that gets the error is a page that redirects to a mediafire (or other download source) link and updates the download count in my database. The error only occurs when the redirect parameter in my url has http:// in it.

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

download.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['uri'])){
        $download_link = $_GET['uri'];
        $download_link = str_replace("///","//",$download_link);


        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        include "include/mysql_connect.php";

        $sql = "SELECT trackid FROM customs WHERE download='$download_link'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);

        if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                $trackid = $row['trackid'];
            }
        }

        else{
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    window.location = \"index.php\";
</script>";
            return;
        }

        if($trackid != ""){
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE song='$trackid'");
            if (!$query or mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
                //If it doesn't exist, create the row
                $t = mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloads SET song='$trackid', count=1, date=NOW()");
            } else {
                //If it does, add one to the counter
                $t = mysql_query("UPDATE downloads SET count=count+1, date=NOW() WHERE song='$trackid'");
            }
        }

        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    window.location = \"$download_link\"
</script>";
    }

    else{
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    window.location = \"index.php\";
</script>";
    }
?>
```

.htaccess (has no rules for this download.php whatsoever.):

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

Redirect /unsubscribe http://ttrcustoms.us/#account=edit
Redirect /cydia http://repo.ttrcustoms.us
Redirect /Cydia http://repo.ttrcustoms.us
Redirect /repo http://repo.ttrcustoms.us
Redirect /tools http://tools.ttrcustoms.us

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^repo/deb/(.*)\.deb$ /download.php?package=$1.deb [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$) /include/retinaimages.php?img=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It is hard to detect where the problem is just looking at the code. Maybe a script to handle 403 errors will help you to do it. Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543800/selecting-for-special-characters-with-rewriterule-in-htaccess-file/14546063#comment20376608_14546063) in case you want to give it a try. The `error.log` file is also a great tool to find out what's going on.

Comment: I've checked my error log, it had nothing but errors from another script that I need to reconfigure because it still uses a previous mySQL password.

Comment: Also, I'd rather find the cause of this error than find a way to bypass it.

Comment: The error handler will help you to find out the source of the problem by checking the incoming server variables with the appropriate PHP code. Not to bypass the error, but to be able to correct it. But, that's just an idea.

Comment: Oh right, I didnt read it properly sorry :p anyway, the error output still doesnt really make me any wiser.

Comment: This is what the script returns in a browser that never previously visited the page:
array(2) { ["__utma"]=> string(54) "59627240.1752886037.1345796511.1349512643.1351187895.9" ["__utmz"]=> string(69) "59627240.1345796511.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)" }

Comment: Use this PHP code `<?php echo var_dump($_SERVER) . "<br /><br />"; ?>` to display the server variables.

Comment: Apparently it were some new security measures my web host took, I solved it by using download ID's rather than the download url in my script.